# Secondary axis with twinx how to add to legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

Why isn't the second legend shown when I've written my code this way? I want it in the same as the one that is printed.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import json

f = open ('kaffeTeData.json')
år, kaffe, te = json.load(f)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()


ax1.set_xlabel('år', fontsize = 15)
ax1.set_ylabel('kaffe [kg per person och år]', color = 'tab:red', fontsize = 15)   
ax1.plot(år, kaffe, color = 'tab:red', label = 'kaffe')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='tab:red')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()           #Sätt den en axel likamed den andra axel, för att de delar samma x-axel.
     

ax2.set_ylabel('te [kg per person och år]', color = 'tab:green', fontsize = 15)
ax2.plot(år, te, color = 'tab:green', label = 'te')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor = 'tab:green')

plt.title('Konsumtionen av kaffe och te i Sverige \n 1960 - 2021', loc = 'center', fontsize = 15 )

ax1.set_ylim(6, 12)
ax2.set_ylim(0.10, 0.50)
ax1.grid()
ax1.set_facecolor('xkcd:very light pink')
fig. tight_layout()

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The data in the json file is.

```
år = ([1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021])

kaffe = ([7.99, 8.11, 8.85, 9.39, 9.72, 9.85, 10.0, 10.56, 10.85, 10.73, 10.84, 10.69, 10.64, 10.66, 10.69, 10.77, 11.29, 8.12, 9.26, 9.62, 9.57, 9.62, 9.49, 8.93, 9.38, 8.96, 8.88, 8.98, 8.8, 8.84, 8.96, 8.85, 8.53, 8.53, 8.73, 7.5, 8.45, 7.7, 7.55, 7.5, 6.95, 7.0, 7.55, 7.49, 7.86, 7.73, 8.13, 7.98, 7.97, 7.96, 8.83, 7.34, 7.97, 8.11, 7.46, 7.51, 8.29, 7.57, 7.5, 7.79, 7.7, 6.47])

te = ([0.13, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.17, 0.19, 0.19, 0.2, 0.24, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.32, 0.33, 0.44, 0.33, 0.36, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.35, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.37, 0.3, 0.31, 0.34, 0.32, 0.3, 0.31, 0.33, 0.28, 0.32, 0.33, 0.32, 0.33, 0.36, 0.27, 0.31, 0.29, 0.32, 0.3, 0.24, 0.37, 0.4, 0.41, 0.37, 0.32, 0.29, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.33, 0.3, 0.28, 0.26, 0.26, 0.25])
```

I've looked around and can't find a solution

Comment: should set legend with `ax1` and `ax2` instead of `plt`. IIRC, `plt.legend` sets the legend in the last active axis.